# How do you get specific generic method overload from static class using reflection?

Tags: c#, methods, reflection, static

so I have a static class:

```
class static EnumHelper {
   public string GetCode<E>(E value) where E: struct {}

   public string GetCode<E>(E? value) where E: struct {}
}
```

however using:

```
typeof(EnumHelper).GetMethod("GetCode")
```

always returns this error:

> System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.

However, i can't directly use the overload of GetMethod providing the "parameter types" because the parameter type are based upon the generic type argument defined in the method itself.

The goal is to:

```
//given parameter: T item
MethodInfo mi = typeof(EnumHelper).GetMehod("GetCode");
mi.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
mi.Invoke(null, new object[] {item});
```

but I'm having trouble at the "GetMethod" part of this equation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you're going to need to disambiguate between them manually, perhaps by using `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` and testing whether it is `null` or `not null`, to pick between them. For example, for find the `E value` version:

```cs
var method = typeof(EnumHelper).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
  .Single(method => method.Name == nameof(EnumHelper.GetCode)
  && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(method.GetParameters().Single().ParameterType) is null);
```

The same but `is not null` gives you the `E?` version.

Answer (score 0):

`EnumHelper` has two different methods with the same name, so "default" `GetMethod` can't choose between them. You need to figure out the nullability of `T` and needed method manually.

Depending on version of framework you are using you can either perform filtering on all methods:

```
var type = typeof(T);
var sourceTypeNullable = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null;
var mi = typeof(EnumHelper)
   .GetMethods()
   .Where(mi => mi.Name == "GetCode")
   .Where(mi => mi.GetParameters() == 1)
   .Where(mi => sourceTypeNullable == (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(mi.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType) != null))
   .Single();

var constructed = mi.MakeGenericMethod(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) ?? type);
constructed.Invoke(...);
```

Or use [`Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenericmethodparameter?view=net-5.0) (which is available since .NET Core 2.1) which allows to build generic parameter descriptor and pass it to [`GetMethod` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=net-5.0#System_Type_GetMethod_System_String_System_Type___) accepting collection of `Type` objects representing parameters of the searched method:

```
var genericType = Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0);
genericType = sourceTypeNullable 
   ? Type.MakeGenericSignatureType(typeof(Nullable<>), genericType) // or typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(genericType) for pre 3.0 versions
   : genericType;
var mi = typeof(EnumHelper).GetMethod(nameof(EnumHelper.GetCode), new[] {genericType});
constructed = mi.MakeGenericMethod(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) ?? type);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select one or another based on whether the type of the parameter and the type argument are the same:

```cs
var mi = (from m in typeof(EnumHelper).GetMethods()
        where m.Name == "GetCode"
        let targ = m.GetGenericArguments()[0]
        let param = m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType
        where targ != param // and == for the non-nullable version
        select m).Single();

    Type tArg = typeof(ConsoleColor);
    var value = ConsoleColor.Black;
    mi.MakeGenericMethod(tArg).Invoke(null, new object[] {value});
```

See also the live example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DhabX4).